# Use curl to send a GET request using basic authentication where the password starts with a question mark character '?'

Tags: windows, authentication, curl, cmd, command

I'm having some trouble with using sending a request where a password starts with ?

For example:

> curl -u admin:?password http://192.168.16.54/index.htm?misseddel=clear

Comes back as unauthorised, even if the password is correct.

%3F doesn't work as a replacement for ? (even when trying in chrome/edge)

Any ideas? Not able to change this password unfortunately.

Comment: it might require escaping `\?`

Comment: Good idea, though i tried it already to no avail :(

Comment: I do not access to curl noe but let me see what I can figure out.